# how do I reverse a stack using another stack in java

Tags: java, stack

Hi I am trying to reverse a stack(one I coded myself) using another empty stack. For some reason it is not working properly. Can anyone help me with this ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack stack1 = new Stack();

        //filling the stack with numbers from 0 to 4
        for(int i = 0; i < Constants.MAX_ELMNTS; i++){

            stack1.push(new Integer(i));
            System.out.println(i);
    }   


    Stack reverse = new Stack();

    while(stack1.getNbElements() > 0){

        reverse.push(stack1.pop());
    }
```

Comment: please define "not working properly". Also you populate variable `stack` in first loop and use variable `stack1` in the second loop.

Comment: You're showing us code you use to test your class. What you should really be showing us is the code for push and pop (and perhaps getNbElements() too)

Comment: Since this is a custom stack, the actual implementation is required before suggesting the optimal strategy for reverse().

Comment: Update i'm 99% sure it's working but I don't know how to output reverse. It outputs:"stack@1540e19d". What is this ?

Comment: @DoctorLongLegs I have updated the answer to include output of the values.

Comment: Yes it's working thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 while(!stack1.isEmpty()){
        Integer value = (Integer)stack1.pop();
        System.out.println(value);
        reverse.push(value);
 }
```